# Passing parameters in SQLite in Python/Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, web, flask, server

I have a very dumb issue which I've been absolutely breaking my head over for a while now

```
##########CODE 1 (STATIC)##############
@app.route('/fromdb', methods=['GET'])
def printall():

data = g.db.execute("SELECT TeacherInfo.Name, TeacherInfo.PhoneNo, TeacherInfo.HourlyRate, SubjectTable.SubjectName, SubjectTable.Grade, SubjectTable.Syllabus FROM SubjectTable JOIN TeacherInfo on SubjectTable.TeacherID = TeacherInfo.TeacherID WHERE SubjectName = 'Comp'").fetchall()
   print(data)
   return jsonify(details=data)
##########END CODE1###################


##########CODE 2(DYNAMIC)#############
@app.route('/fromdb', methods=['GET'])
def printall():

   x = request.json

   p = x['SubjectName']

   data = g.db.execute("SELECT TeacherInfo.Name, TeacherInfo.PhoneNo, TeacherInfo.HourlyRate, SubjectTable.SubjectName, SubjectTable.Grade, SubjectTable.Syllabus FROM SubjectTable JOIN TeacherInfo on SubjectTable.TeacherID = TeacherInfo.TeacherID WHERE SubjectName = ?", p).fetchall()
   print(data)
   return jsonify(details=data)
##########END CODE2###################
```

In the link above, there are two codes
Code 1 works perfectly fine, **I'm focusing on the 'WHERE SubjectName = 'Comp'' and WHERE SubjectName = ?** here

I hard code the subject name into the query, and I get a JSON object with the results of the query

Now, in code 2, the variable 'p' contains the subject name and I'm able to retrieve it and print it. But the query isn't working, I'm getting a 500 error and I'm not sure how I pass it as a parameter in the query.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error? You should be able to get this from the web server error log. If you're using apache and ubuntu, you can find the error log on /var/log/apache/error.log.

Comment: I'm using nginx and ubuntu and I found the error.log in /var/log/nginx/error.log but it's empty

Comment: The nginx error log won't have the error for the python app. How are you running the app? uwsgi? Apache? You can either setup logging in the app to say, log all errors to a log file. Or you can run the app in the foreground and get nginx to proxy to that.